# How to make an optimal DTO mapping in Kotlin backend?

Tags: spring, kotlin, backend, dto

My approach is something like I have my entity class let's say:

```
data class User(
  private val name: String,
  private val age: Int
)
```

And I have a DTO:

```
data class UserDto(
  val name: String,
  val age: Int
)
```

And the mapper function is an extension function of User (inside my class file):

```
User.mapToDto(UserDto u) {
  this.name = u.name
  this.age = u.age
}
```

My doubt is if this approach it is the best, because my DTO doesn't have private modifiers thinking it is a val attribute (so it will not be changed). Or there is a best way to do this, respecting concepts like encapsulation and all that clean code other stuff.

I already tried to make a mapper (in another file) but does not work because my entity class has private access, so it makes necessary to do it inside my class User.

Answer (score 1):

I have a take on this question. First, the common approach that I commonly use is to have an extension function that maps an entity to its DTO.The approach is

```
data class User(
    private val name: String,
    private val age: Int
)

data class UserDto(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int
)

fun User.mapToDto(): UserDto {
    return UserDto(name, age)
}
```

This approach makes sure that our code is aligned with the immutability principle.But in your case you have a private properties in your data class and if I use my first approach then I violate the encapsualtion principle. So to resolve this issue we have a second approach that is

```
data class User(
    private val name: String,
    private val age: Int
) {
    fun getName(): String = name
    fun getAge(): Int = age
}

data class UserDto(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int
)

fun User.mapToDto(): UserDto {
    return UserDto(getName(), getAge())
}
```

So now our second approach allows better control over the internal affairs on our codebase and alligining with encapsulation principal

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constructor or an (extension) function *returning* the object.

With a constructor, it would look like that:

```kotlin
data class UserDto(
  val name: String,
  val age: Int
){
    constructor(user: User) :  this(user.name, user.age){}
}
```

```kotlin
val dto = UserDto(user);
```

With an extension function, you can use the existing constructor:

```kotlin
fun User.mapToDto() =
    UserDto(name, age);
```

```kotlin
val dto = user.mapToDto();
```

Note that both these methods require `name` and `age` to be accessible.
If you don't want that, you need to add that method to `User`:

```kotlin
data class User(
  private val name: String,
  private val age: Int
){
    fun mapToDto() {
        return UserDto(name, age);
    }  
}
```

Which option you choose is up to you and your opinions.

Comment: do you create your dto classes with the private access modifier?

Comment: I am normally not using Kotlin but Java. There, I typically either use records (where all components can be read from other classes) or `private` fields that at least have getters. What's the point of having a DTO if there's no way to access its components?